# Phoenix alter model

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

What is the correct way to alter a ecto model in Phoenix?

So far I've created a `Post` model which contains a `title` and a `content` string field. I added the resource to the router to create and view the Posts.
Now I would like to add a `author` field to my model.
What I did until now is the following:

I created a migration with

```
mix ecto.gen.migration add_author_to_post
```

In the migrationfile I inserted

```
alter table(:posts) do
  add :author, :string
end
```

and ran the migration with `mix ecto.migrate`.
Now the coloumn is visible in the database.
Then I added the fileld to my model file:

```
schema "posts" do 
  field :title, :string
  field :content, :string
  field :author, :string
  timestamps
end

@required_fields ~w(title content author)
@optional_fields ~w()
```

But when I visit the page to add a new Post, there is no field to add an author in the html.file. 
(The `new.html.eex` file was generated by the `mix phoenix.gen.html`)

*PS: I'm sure this is a basic beginner question. But since the phoenixcommunity is quite small, this question might be usefull for lots of other people*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template is not based on the current schema defined in your model. It is based on what you pass the `mix phoenix.gen.html` task.

You will need to update your template to include the author in `web/templates/post/form.html.eex`

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Author</label>
    <%= text_input f, :author, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ahh yes.. sure. This was too easy.

Comment: I notices I had to use `:author_id` insdead of `:author`

Comment: @0xAffe If that is the case then your current schema does not match the schema you posted in the question.